# How to correct the time-zone with date-fns?

Tags: typescript, timezone, locale, utc, date-fns

(see this example online: https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-fns-playground-zeitzonen?file=index.ts -> Console output)

Following situation, it is 11:54 AM:

```js
// Setup
const dateString = "2020-08-30T11:54:48.200Z";    // <---- 11:54 AM
const tz = "Europe/Berlin";
const dateFormat = "d. MMM yyyy, E HH:mm";
const dateOptions = { locale: de };
```

As far as I format the date, it changes its time-zone and adds 2 more hours:

```js
const parsedDate = parseISO(dateString);

const formattedDate = format(parsedDate, dateFormat, dateOptions);
// outputs: 30. Aug 2020, So. 13:54

const zonedDate = utcToZonedTime(dateString, tz);
// outputs: 2020-08-30T11:54:48.200Z

const formattedZonedDate =  format(zonedDate, dateFormat, dateOptions);
// outputs: 30. Aug 2020, So. 13:54
```

The desired (correct) output would be `30. Aug 2020, So. 11:54`

Where is my mistake? Does the initial `dateString` have the correct time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the initial dateString have the correct time zone?

Not if you expect it to be in Berlin time, no. The "Z" at the end means "UTC" - so your string represents 11:54 UTC, which would indeed by 13:54 in Berlin. The formatting is doing the right thing in my view.

It's not entirely clear to me why `utcToZonedDateTime` is still reporting a UTC value rather than the zoned version, admittedly.

If you want `dateString` to represent a local time, it should probably be "2020-08-30T11:54:48.200". If, on the other hand, you want it to represent a UTC time that *is* at 11:54 in Berlin, it should be "2020-08-30T09:54:48.200Z" - note the change in hour to 09.